# How to make my papers accessible to other researchers?

Tags: publications, open-access

I have published some papers in some conferences, but the problem is that the people in charge put them in bibliographic repositories, such as DBLP, and they take too much time to do that.

I would like to know how I can allow more people access to my publications, so they would be able to review them, use them if they want, maybe bring more ideas or even suggest that I correct something.

Initially, I was putting them in a personal webpage that I have created, but I took them off because I also got some papers accepted by ACM and IEEE and they require a payment to see them. In this last case, if I upload them for free (on my personal webpage) could I be charged with something by these institutions?

Comment: Related: [Advertising one's publication](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3456/advertising-ones-publication)

Comment: You can use the http://academia.edu/ which is directly purported to share research news and articles.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From the context of your question, I assume you are a computer scientist graduate student.  (Computer scientist because you mention DBLP, and graduate student because you're worried about people finding your research *quickly*.) My answer is specific to computer science, **especially the first two points.**

- **Just post your papers on your web page already.**   Among other things, posting your own papers will allow Google Scholar to find and index them after only a few days. Despite scary legal language to the contrary, neither ACM nor IEEE (or SIAM, or AMS, or Springer, or Elsevier, or...) has any interest in suing individual researchers for providing copies of their own papers.
- **Post preprints of your work to the ArXiv and/or your institutional preprint server.**  Again, despite scary language to the contrary, granting a license to the ArXiv to publish your papers does not deprive ACM or IEEE (or SIAM, or AMS, or Springer, or Elsevier, or even ACS) the right to later publish peer-reviewed version of your papers later.  Many publishers explicitly allow you to publish post-reviewed but pre-copy-edited preprints on the ArXiv and similar servers.  Posting camera-ready versions is technically illegal, but neither ACM nor IEEE has any interest in suing individual users for such violations.
- **Post publication announcements on Facebook/Google+/Twitter/your blog.**  Yes, this works.  Really.
- **Give lots of talks.**  At a minimum, you should give talks about your results in an appropriate local seminar.  But especially for really strong results, you (or your advisor) should also [arrange to have yourself invited](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/1944/how-to-invite-yourself-to-present-at-another-university) to a few other institutions to give a talk.
- **Send copies of your work directly to a few colleagues.**  Just send them email with a link to your web page.  (*Don't* blindly send papers as attachments; remember that some people read email over the phone and pay by the byte.)  But don't just spam the whole world.  Limit your email to the small handful of influential people that you are *sure* will be interested — other researchers working on the same problem, people whose results you directly improve or extend, your advisor, and—**if** you're nearing a point like graduation or tenure where you need letters—a few potential letter-writers.
- **Take the long view.**  It really is not important that see your results RIGHT NOW THIS MINUTE ZOMG NOW NOW NOW !!!!111¡¡¡CXI.  Relax.  Yes, DBLP and other indexing services operate with a delay of several months.  (Although my impression is DBLP has gotten faster, thanks to some outside funding that allowed them to hire more than one human being.)  And yeah, that's frustrating.  But in the long run, those few months of publication delay are not going to make a bit of difference.

Comment: +1 for "Just post your papers on your web page already." I have never heard of anyone getting into any trouble for this, nor even of publishers demanding that such papers be taken down.

Comment: Posting one one's own page is great, but most likely, will not last forever (because one changes university, because one forget's to pay for one's domain, etc). So, whether possible, posting on arXiv may be of higher importance.

Comment: I would argue that this answer is important in a bigger context i.e. web presence of a graduate student in today's world. In my personal experience twitter works best at disseminating published work. There are some interesting studies done in that context namely this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22173204

Comment: @Anonymous: As I mentioned below, some _very_ major publishers do **not** allow this! You must check with the journals to see what is and is not permitted according to their policy.

Answer (score 11):

You need to check with the specific rules of the journals to which you submit to determine what is or is not allowed. For instance, journals published by the [American Institute of Physics](http://journals.aip.org) allow you to publish preprints that are not created by the journal on servers like [arXiv](http://www.arXiv.org) without having to pay any fees and without other major limitations. By contrast, [American Chemical Society](http://pubs.acs.org) journals do not allow you to post preprints, *even on your own homepage*. You can link to their site, and after twelve months, the link becomes effectively "free."

But, beyond that, if you want to advertise your work, you will have to do it yourself. You can mention in it in presentations, and cite it in abstracts that you submit to other conferences. You can email colleagues or use social media (sites like [academia.edu](http://academia.edu), [LinkedIn](http://linkedin.com) or even [Facebook](http://facebook.com) to announce your paper. If you have specific colleagues you think would be interested in the paper, you can send it directly to them as well!

Comment: **This is simply not an issue in computer science.**  Scary legal language notwithstanding, no major computer science publisher is interested in going after individual researchers for posting their own work on their personal web pages.

Comment: Fair enough, but this isn't flagged as an exclusively CS question, and this question will almost certainly be read by people who aren't CS people.

Comment: Actually I was thinking of asking similar question (as OP), since I've seen some publishers pursuing authors while some others not taking action. I'm coming from social science and this answer helps.

Answer (score 5):

You should **read the copyright transfer contract** that you have signed.

In general, the major publishers tend to be fairly permissive nowadays as regards to online posting.

---

With [**ACM conference publications**](http://www.acm.org/publications/policies/copyright_policy#Retained), you can (and **should**) do all of the following:

- *Before* you submit the paper, post it to **arXiv.org**.
- *After* your paper has been accepted, post your *own* version of the paper (with an appropriate copyright notice) on:

  1. your own **personal web page**, and
  2. your **university's open access repository**.
- *Later* you can prepare a journal version ("major revision"), and you can do with it whatever you want — for example, submit it to an **open access journal**, post it online, etc.

---

With [**IEEE conference publications**](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/publications/rights/copyrightmain.html), the main idea is similar: you *can* post your work to **arXiv.org** before submission and to your **own home page** and a **university-wide open access repository** after revision.

However, some details are a bit different. My reading of the policies is that with ACM you *cannot* update arXiv.org with a revised version, while IEEE *requires* that you update arXiv.org with the accepted version of the paper.

However, don't take my word, read the copyright transfer form (and additional explanations available on the publishers' web pages).

Comment: Thank You for delving on when to post a paper on arXiv viz. before submitting the paper/paper notification!

Answer (score 4):

You should check the conditions of your journal using the [SHERPA/RoMEO](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) list. Most journals allow to publish your **final draft** (designed and typeset by yourself) on your institutes server right after publication and on open-access servers like [arXiv.org](http://arXiv.org) 12 month after publication. Your institutes open-access server will also be found by e.g. Google Scholar.
Many journals will also send you an **authors copy** of your article which you can share with colleagues (e.g. via email) but you should not publish that one on the internet.