# Can you list a "last-minute" invited talk on your CV?

Tags: conference, cv, presentation

A session at an annual professional society meeting that I regularly help to organize includes an "invited" talk to anchor the session. Some years, the invited speaker is unable to attend the meeting (due to illness, travel problems, etc.). If we are able to arrange a last-minute substitute speaker to fill the time slot (rather than canceling it and risking losing the audience to other parallel sessions), would that speaker be able to list the talk as an "invited" talk on her CV, even though it's not been advertised or listed anywhere?

Comment: If talks I [invite myself to give](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/23353/should-i-list-talks-i-invited-myself-to-give-on-my-cv) count, I'm pretty sure this does too.

Comment: @ff524: The key question, in my opinion, is what to do if there's no documentation of the talk having taken place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not? Of all the possible people to give the (new) talk, you invited that person, and even trusted them to give a good talk on short notice!

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is no difference between first and last minute invited speakers. Nobody mentions in his CV that he is invited in the last days. The important is that he has talked in that conference and this is of value to be mentioned in his CV.

Comment: Also, I do not think that the time of invitation is regularly mentioned in the certificates which may be given to the speakers (if any exists).